# How to filter a list of Maps and display it inside ListView builder | Flutter | Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Here's have a list of appointments :

```
static final appointments = [
    {
      "status": "Upcoming",
      "doctor": {
        "name": "Dr Mahdi CHAKROUN",
        "image": "lib/assets/images/doctor3.png",
        "specialist": "Cardiologue"
      },
      "date": "16 july, 2021",
    },
    {
      "status": "Upcoming",
      "doctor": {
        "name": "Dr Leila Riahi",
        "image": "lib/assets/images/doctor2.png",
        "specialist": "Cardiologue"
      },
      "date": "16 july, 2021",
    },
    {
      "status": "Past",
      "doctor": {
        "name": "Dr Mahdi CHAKROUN",
        "image": "lib/assets/images/doctor3.png",
        "specialist": "Cardiologue"
      },
      "date": "10 july, 2021",
    },
    {
      "status": "Past",
      "doctor": {
        "name": "Dr Mahdi CHAKROUN",
        "image": "lib/assets/images/doctor.png",
        "specialist": "Orthodontist"
      },
      "date": "10 july, 2021",
    },
];
```

Here I'm trying to filter the appointment based on the selected appointment type (Incoming/Past)

```
class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
    String _selectedAppointments = "Incoming";
List<Map<String, Object>?> selectedAppointmentsList =
      Constants.appointments.map((appointment) {
    if (appointment["status"] == "Past") {
      return appointment;
    }
  }).toList();
```

But I got this error, I can't figure it out, any advice how to fix this error ?

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
> The method '[]' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ***where*** to filter instead of 'if' statment

solve the issue by doing:

```
 List<Map<String, Object>?> selectedAppointmentsList =
      Constants.appointments.where((appointment) => appointment["status"] ==_selectedAppointments ).toList();
```